# spring security creating 2 different login forms in one URL

Tags: html, spring-security

I am writing a spring security code with 2 different login forms in one page. What I mean to achieve is this: [There are one login for admin and one login for users separately in one page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3twL.png)

For that I have written the following code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(
                "/registration**",
                "/js/**",
                "/css/**",
                "/img/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/")
            .successForwardUrl("/librarianlogin")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
            
            .permitAll();
            
     
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
}
```

and :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(2)
public class SecurityConfigurationAdmin extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(
                "/registration**",
                "/js/**",
                "/css/**",
                "/img/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/")
            .usernameParameter("username2")
            .passwordParameter("password2")
            .successForwardUrl("/adminlogin")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
            
            .permitAll();
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin").password("{noop}admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

and :

```
public interface UserService extends UserDetailsService{
 User save(Librarians librarians);
}
```

and :

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    public UserServiceImpl() {
        super();
    }
    
    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

 
    @Override
    public User save (Librarians librarians) {
        User user = new User(librarians.getName(),
                librarians.getEmailAddress(),
            passwordEncoder.encode(librarians.getPassword()), Arrays.asList(new Role("ROLE_USER")));

        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.");
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), mapRolesToAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
    }

    private Collection < ? extends GrantedAuthority > mapRolesToAuthorities(Collection < Role > roles) {
        return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
}
```

Html :

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <article class="main">
            <h2 class="page-heading">Admin Login
            </h2>
                <div id="form">
                    <form th:action="@{/}" method="post">
                        <fieldset>
                        <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-danger">
                        Invalid username and password.
                        </div>
                        <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-info">
                        You have been logged out.
                        </div>
                        <p>
                            <label class="row margin-bot" for="username">email</label>
                            <input type="text" id="username2" name="username2" placeholder="email" autofocus="autofocus">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label class="row margin-bot" for="password">pass</label>
                            <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="subject">
                        </p>
                        
                        <p>
                            <input  id="submit" type="submit" name="message" value="sign in">
                        </p>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            
        </article>
        </div> 
        <div class="col">
            <article class="main">
            <h2 class="page-heading">Librarian Login
            </h2>
                <div id="form">
                    <form th:action="@{/}" method="post">
                        <fieldset>
                        <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-danger">
                        Invalid username and password.
                        </div>
                        <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-info">
                        You have been logged out.
                        </div>
                        <p>
                            <label class="row margin-bot" for="username">email</label>
                            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="email" autofocus="autofocus">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label class="row margin-bot" for="password">pass</label>
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="subject">
                        </p>
                        
                        <p>
                            <input  id="submit" type="submit" name="message" value="sign in">
                        </p>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

This code is adopted from login forms in 2 different URLs. Can I use the same logic to achieve my goal too. I have to mention that when I use a single login the program works fine but when I add both login forms the admin login doesnt work.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you take a look at this if possible.

Comment: @Angular University can you take a look at this if possible